# What is I2S channel pair?

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, pcm

I have seen I2S channel pair written at some places. One of the examples is below. 
http://www.minidsp.com/images/documents/USBStreamer%20Manual.pdf

What does channel pair mean here? Does channel pair mean left and Right both channels in stereo sound?

Answer (score 1):

Where I see it mentioned in the linked document the I2S data is run 2 channels per line over four data lines. Something like this:

```
          ________
FCLK: ___|        |________|
D0:       Ch1      Ch2
D1:       Ch3      Ch4
D2:       Ch5      Ch6
D3:       Ch7      Ch8
```

The document page 13 is referring to grouping these into stereo pairs where each pair can be controlled with a single volume slider - as opposed to independent where there are individual sliders for each channel. So the pairs would be (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8). This is all entirely outside of I2S as volume control is happening by the sender or the reader.